# How to find and change local DNS rules?

Tags: dns

I'm trying to understand routing on my machine.

On my VM, there is the address `sandbox-hdp-security` that resolves to `127.0.0.1`.

```
>  dig sandbox-hdp-security

;; ANSWER SECTION:
sandbox-hdp-security.   600     IN      A       172.18.0.2

;; Query time: 305 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.11#53(127.0.0.11)
```

(part of response redacted for readibility)

I see that this address is resolved to IP by `127.0.0.11` (DNS). It looks like local IP address and as expected other machine in network didn't point to `127.0.0.1` on similar `dig` command.

I suspect that this DNS is local to my machine (Internet sources suggest that it's somehow created by Docker, but to best of my knowledge I don't use Docker on my VM).

If that's true (it's local DNS) then I think its configuration should be on ths machine and I probably should be able to find it, read it and change it.

How can I do something  like that?

PS. I try to resolve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51649812/change-default-api-path-for-ambari) - there are more details about my setup. If more information is needed, I'll update my question.

**EDIT(1):**

It's Hortonworks Sandbox running on Oracle VM VirtualBox:

```
> uname -a
Linux sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com 4.17.2-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Jun 16 11:18:11 EDT 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Background

Yes 127.0.0.11 is a local instance of a DNS server likely running in the Hortonworks VM. It's listening on port 53. You know this per this line in the `dig` response:

> ;; SERVER: 127.0.0.11#53(127.0.0.11)

#### localhost*

Most people are surprised to find out that there's more than just the well known IP of 127.0.0.1 for localhost. It's in fact a `/8` in terms of address space:

```
$ ip a l lo
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

So addresses such as 127.0.0.2, etc. are all addresses that a system can use internally for whatever is deemed necessary. In this case the DNS server is bound to port 53 on that IP address.

#### ss

You can confirm by looking for using the `ss` command:

```
$ ss -ltpn '( sport = :53 )' | less
State      Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address:Port               Peer Address:Port
LISTEN     0      5            *:53                       *:*                   users:(("dnsmasq",pid=24086,fd=7))
LISTEN     0      5           :::53                      :::*                   users:(("dnsmasq",pid=24086,fd=9))
(END)
```

In the above we can see that `dnsmasq` which is PID 24086 is the process that's listening on port 53.

#### lsof

Once we know the PID, we can start to look at it to figure out what files it's using:

```
$ lsof -p 24086 | grep -E '/etc|/var'
dnsmasq 24086 dnsmasq    3u      REG  179,2     1103 128324 /etc/pihole/dhcp.leases
dnsmasq 24086 dnsmasq   13w      REG  179,2  3201111  20530 /var/log/pihole.log
```

**NOTE:** Keep in mind, most service daemons will typically open their config files, read them, and then close them, so don't be alarmed if we don't see any configuration files in the above output.

From the above you can follow the log file to figure out how to reconfigure whatever DNS server you happen to be dealing with.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it doesn't address my question. I'm looking for a way to inspect this DNS and possibly change it (I guess it's possible given that it is local DNS).

Comment: We need to determine the DNS server 1st (as I showed how) before we can answer that. Of course, it's local to the VM you can do whatever you want to it. But i can't tell you how to edit every type of DNS server software, we need to know which we're dealing w/ 1st.

Comment: You need to be root when running these commands, BTW, or  using `sudo` at least. Also you can use `/etc/hosts` if it's a single node of Hadoop. Night.

Comment: @slm `ss`, `lsof` or `netstat` don't show anything on port 53 (whats more on `127.0.0.11` there is only somethong on port `37161` (and without any process - empty space)). I use `root` account and tested with `sudo` (shouldn't matter). My `/etc/hosts` doesn't oofer much help (maybe this `172.18.0.2      sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com sandbox-hdp`). It's different address

Comment: @hellomoto Sorry, for unclear question. In `resolv.conf` I have line `nameserver 127.0.0.11`. I know that I have to use at least two DNSs, but I'm interested in the one, that resolves `sandbox-hdp-security` (end `dig` says that is the one on `127.0.0.11`). I didn't consider role of DHCP - I'll try to find something about that. I know that it isn't resolved on local network level, but logs suggest that it's resolved on my machine.

Comment: @hellomoto Yes, I agree. I don't use net for this connection. But this mapping (like `sandbox-hdp-security` -> `localhost:8080`) has come  from somewhere. If there is no net usage, then it's coming from my machine. And I try to locate this. It seems that DHCP doesn't matter in this situation (addresses should be static).

Comment: Try sudo netstat -napl | grep 8080

Comment: I can connect to `localhost:8080` or to `192.168.1.XX:8080` and get to Web Interface from my host machine (where VM is running). I'd like to inspect the DNS that allows to connect to from inside VM to `sandbox-hdp-security:8080` (I cannot to connect to this address from host machine).

Comment: @franiis - I wouldn't necessarily expect anything to show up as actually listening on 127.0.0.11, given it maps to localhost, anything listening on *:53 will respond. Can you please confirm if you're using just the vanilla HDP sandbox VM? I can pull it down and see what's up inside as well.

Comment: @slm Yes, it's clear Sandbox. I only forwarded all ports in Oracle VM VirtualBox VM's network configuration (so it's discoverable outside host machine, but I'm quite sure, that it doesn't effect Guest OS - Sandbox). I have same problem on two instances of Sandbox - mine and colleague's.